# C++, getting name of the plugin from derived class

Tags: c++11

I have a requirement wherein, I need to create a base class which will have some pure virtual functions which would be implemented by derived classes. These virtual functions are not enough and I also need to get the name of the plugin to be given to a library from the base class which I will create.
I am using factory pattern. Basically thought that based on the plugin name I would create the instance of that particular derived class.
But, the problem here is since I am using factory pattern, until I send plugin name I would not create object and until object is created plugin name would not be known. Because of this I always see empty plugin name.

Many plugins would be derived from this common base class, it's important to know name of the plugin at runtime.

Please suggest

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a factory for each plugin type in your central factory.

```
struct common_args {
  int width; // whatever
};

struct BasePlugin {
  virtual ~BasePlugin() {}
  virtual std::string get_name() const = 0;
  virtual void do_stuff() = 0;
};

using single_type_factory = std::function<std::unique_ptr<BasePlugin>( common_args ) >;

using plugin_factory = std::function<std::unique_ptr<BasePlugin>( std::string name, common_args ) >;

struct central_factory:plugin_factory {
  central_factory(central_factory&&)=delete;
  central_factory():
    plugin_factory(
      [this](std::string name, common_args args)
      ->std::unique_ptr<BasePlugin>
      {
        auto it = m_factories.find(name);
        if (it == m_factories.end())
          return {};
        return (*it)(args);
      }
    )
  {}
  void register_plugin_type( std::string name, single_type_factory f ) {
    m_factories[name] = f;
  }
private:
  std::unordered_map<std::string, single_type_factory> m_factories;
};
```

that is just a sketch.